# Toast isn't showing, here is my code, please tell whats wrong

Tags: java, android, toast, android-toast

I am just learning to develop the apps through udemy course. and learning to create a simple currency converter, the code looks exactly the same as in the course, but their toast is working, but mine isn't.

```java
public void convert(View view){

    EditText amount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.addAmount);

    Double dollarAmount = Double.parseDouble(amount.getText().toString());
    Double poundAmount = dollarAmount * 0.73;

    Log.i("£", poundAmount.toString());

    Toast.makeText(
        getApplicationContext(),
        "£" + poundAmount.toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
    ).show();
}
```

Comment: do you have any error?

Comment: show the full code

Comment: are you actually calling the `convert`function?

Comment: @YakirMalka no it doesn't show error, but toast doesn't show, when I changed to log.i then I could see the result

Comment: @Amitpandey i deleted the project. but it was learning through udemy, and i had imported necessary bundles and stuff.

Comment: @Jameido yes i am calling the convert function.

Answer (score -2):

Please make sure that you have the following imported:
import java.util.*;
import android.view.View;

Comment: yes i had imported. i set my android studio to auto-import bundles and auto remove when a bundle is not in use

Comment: I have another question is this on the main thread?